# Are the following assertions true if P != NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np, clique, polynomial-time-reductions

We consider the NP-complete $CLIQUE$ problem. Let furthermore $MST^*$ be the minimum spanning tree problem. Assume that $P \ne NP$ and explain whether the following assertions hold:

1. $MST^* \le_{P} CLIQUE$
2. $CLIQUE \le_{P} MST^*$

**Definitions**: 
$\le_{P}$ ... Karp reduction 
$MST^*$ ... Given is a weighted graph $G$ and a number $k$. Does $G$ have a spanning tree with the total cost $\le k$? (problem lies in P)
$CLIQUE$ ... A clique in a graph is a subset $S$ of the nodes such that all nodes in $S$ are connected in pairs. In the $CLIQUE$ problem we are given
a graph and a number $k$ as input and must decide whether there is a clique with $\vert S \vert \le k$. (problem is NP-complete)

**Question:**
Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you define CLIQUE and MST*? Also, just to be sure, by $\le_P$ you mean a Karp reduction?

Comment: I have now added the definitions

Comment: If $A$ is NP-complete, $B$ is in $P$, and $A \le_P B$, then $P=NP$. Moreover, if $B$ is in $P$ then it is in $NP$ and if $A$ is NP-complete then $A$ must be $NP$-hard. The above two observations imply the answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at the definition of NP-complete, it might help.
2. How fast can we compute $MST^*$? Try to use this in conjunction with the assumption you made.